# Using PHP to add to a database created in WAMP server?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

Ok, so after installing wamp server, I have gone to the phpMyAdmin page and created a database called db2. After that, I have created a table inside of that database called cnt2. It has 5 columns, ID, Name, Mark1, Mark2 and Mark3. So, I have one html php file that allows you to view the information in the database, and this works just fine. However, my second html php document is supposed to allow you to add new information into the database. I have followed 2 different tutorials on this as I have never done php or any html script before, but it just isn't working. I'll post both codes/scripts below.

http://gyazo.com/467f8e3a066992c0753eec2d5912bdba   << Database page

http://gyazo.com/82a1c2107fb75c4c2941583449b4504a  << Input page with error

Database code

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

$selected = mysql_select_db("db2",$dbhandle)
    or die("Could not selected db2");
echo "Coneted to db2<br>", "<br>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3 FROM cnt2");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<b>Name: </b>".$row{'Name'}." <b>ID: </b>".$row{'ID'}." <b>First Mark: </b>".$row{'Mark1'}." <b>Second Mark: </b>".$row{'Mark2'}." <b>Third Mark: </b>".$row{'Mark3'}."<br>";
}

mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Input code

```
<HTML>
<?php

if($submit){
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
    mysql_select_db("db",$db);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cnt2 (ID, Name, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3) VALUES ('$id','$name','$markone','$marktwo','$markthree','$result = mysql_query($sql))";
    echo "Thanks! Data received and entered.\n";
}

else{
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="datain.php">
    id:<input type="Int" name="ID"><br>
    name:<input type="Text" name="Name"><br>
    markone:<input type="Int" name="Mark1"><br>
    marktwo:<input type="Int" name="Mark2"><br>
    markthree:<input type="Int" name="Mark3"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Enter information">
    </form>
<?  
}

?>
</HTML>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please, looking at your code, I'm guessing you're still learning PHP. If so, don't waste your time learning a ***deprecated*** extension like `mysql_*` is. Learn to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. Both have things going for them: `PDO` offers (IMO) the cleanest API, though it's OOP only. `mysqli_*` ofers a procedural _and_ an OO API, and may be a bit more confusing, and tedious to learn, but in its code, it is slightly more powerful when writing more complex DB-driven apps

Comment: On your insert statement it looks like you have more inserting values than you have columns.  I would check this as a start.

Comment: You are sure that your insert code is exactly the same as in the file? Because $result = mysql_query(.. is a value in the code you posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually requesting your post headers to pull your vars in

```
<html>
<?php

if($submit){
    //need to request post vars here
    $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
    $markone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mark1']);
    $marktwo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mark2']);
    $markthree=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mark3']);


    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
    mysql_select_db("db",$db);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cnt2 (ID, Name, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3) VALUES ('$id','$name','$markone','$marktwo','$markthree')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()."<br />".$sql);
    echo "Thanks! Data received and entered.\n";
}

else{
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="datain.php">
    id:<input type="Int" name="ID"><br>
    name:<input type="Text" name="Name"><br>
    markone:<input type="Int" name="Mark1"><br>
    marktwo:<input type="Int" name="Mark2"><br>
    markthree:<input type="Int" name="Mark3"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Enter information">
    </form>
<?php  // stop using short tags i've swapped it to a proper open
}

?>
</html>
```

Also if you're only just using don't use mysql_ functions look into mysqli or pdo especially prepared statements instead of directly injecting variables into queries as we have done above

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this just throws me the same error but on line 33 instead of line 25. I don't really understand this too well, this was literally like our introduction task to php with no real teachning, just a tutorial sheet

Comment: @MarcelBalzer thanks didn't notice that I just copy and pasted his code and added the requests for the post vars

Comment: @DanielSpeed the error is lack of a closing tag in the screen shot means its lacking a } which is due to you using shorttags `<?` instead of a full open `<?php`  never ever ever use short tags

Comment: Oh I see, I'm sorry about that, I have no excuse for that. I've been glued to a tutorial sheet and must have just missed it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cnt2 (ID, Name, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3) VALUES ('$id','$name','$markone','$marktwo','$markthree','$result = mysql_query($sql))";
```

As You may notice (at the end), it should probably be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cnt2 (ID, Name, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3) VALUES ('$id','$name','$markone','$marktwo','$markthree')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

As all other people mentioned, do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are DEPRECATED, instead of this stick with [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or at least [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).

Also, the part

```
if($submit){
```

may never be satisfied unless You set the `$submit` variable somewhere before... Shouldn't it rather be

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

???

And, please, read about *code formatting* - Your code looks like crap... Best choice is to stick with PSR-0, PSR-1 and PSR-3 - use Google to read something about it...

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still gives the same error. I would sit and actually read some stuff on this, but I'll never be using it again. this task is a one off, it's suppose to help us understand some server stuff in one of our lessons, but they're making us actually write it.

Comment: Why are You then learning PHP when You will never use it? Why are we loosing time with somebody who does not will to learn something? And what is the error actually? You didn't mention any error message in Your question...

Comment: We have to complete this task that requires php, which I would be happy to learn, but we do our programming unit using Java. The actually question posted has a link to the error message as a gyazo screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

create database android_api /** Creating Database **/

use android_api /** Selecting Database **/

create table users(
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
); /** Creating Users Table **/

Comment: can you send me how to write in wampserver

Comment: Hi, omkar more, are you trying to ask for help or are you trying to answer the question?